# Accesing the user's search data using Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I was working on an application to analyse the user's information to predict possible health concerns with the user, for which I'll be needing access to the user's google search data and the word choices of the user. Is there any way I can use the Google Admin SDK for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

No, As you can read on the main page for [Google Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk), this API is only to administrate your G Suite domain settings.